# Limit writing in a file with java?

Tags: java, file

I'm trying to copy a file to another file deleting a part of the string like this:

File 1:

```
Name = David  
Age = 21  
M/F = M
```

To file 2:

```
David  
21  
M
```

But the file 1 have 963 lines and its copying only 524 lines.

Is there a limit that java will write (or read) from a file?

What i did to copy it, is it bad?

```
    package replace.strings;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReplaceStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ReplaceStrings rs = new ReplaceStrings();
        try{    
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/tarducciones/traducciones.txt"), true));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/tarducciones/texto.txt"));
            while(sc.hasNext()){                
            String line = sc.nextLine();    
            line = rs.replace(line);            
            bw.write(line);
            bw.newLine();    

            }    
        bw.close();   
        } catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe);
            }
    }

    public String replace(String a){

        int startIndex = a.indexOf("=");
            if (startIndex>0){
            String toBeReplaced = a.substring(0, startIndex+1);
            String resultado = a.replace(toBeReplaced, "");
            return resultado;}
        else return a;
    }
}
```

EDIT: I put the bw outside the loop and still dont work.
EDIT2: Changed like you suggested, but still didnt work and no one exception is catched.
EDIT3: I deleted the first 524 data lines to see if the problem is the data inside the file, and it didnt copy any line. Can it be a problem of the data??? It's only lines in a txt

Comment: The BufferedWriter should be created and closed outside the while loop

Comment: I know, i did, but still dont copy all lines :S
(I just copied the code when i tried using bw in the loop)

Comment: FileWriter can throw an IOException, so bw can be null. Should always close readers and writers in finally block. So: try { your code } finally { if (bw != null) bw.close(); }

Answer (score 1):

Modify your writing code, like:

```
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/tarducciones/traducciones.txt"), true));
    while(sc.hasNext()){
        String line = sc.nextLine();
        // Avoiding creation of new String object.
        bw.write(rs.replace(line));
        bw.newLine();        
    } 
    bw.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

To write content to file, you should close `BufferedWriter` outside of while loop as other answer stated. But, I will recommend to use Java-8. Using Java-8  you can do it more easily using [List#replaceAll](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#replaceAll-java.util.function.UnaryOperator-) method. Have a look at following code.

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));
File output=new File("output.txt");

Stream<String> lines=br.lines();
List<String> lineList=lines.collect(Collectors.toList());
lineList.replaceAll(s->s.substring(s.indexOf('=')+1));

PrintWriter pw=new PrintWriter(output);
lineList.forEach(s-> pw.write(s+"\n"));
pw.close();
```

Comment: Sorry im not using java-8 sorry!

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
package replace.strings;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ReplaceStrings {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
        ReplaceStrings rs = new ReplaceStrings();
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("C:/tarducciones/traducciones.txt"), true));
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("C:/tarducciones/texto.txt"));
        while(sc.hasNext()){
            String line = sc.nextLine();    
            String nueva = rs.replace(line);
            bw.write(nueva);
            bw.newLine();
        }
        bw.close();
    }

    public String replace(String a){
        String str = a;
        int startIndex = a.indexOf("=");
        if (startIndex>0){
            String toBeReplaced = str.substring(0, startIndex+1);
            String resultado = str.replace(toBeReplaced, "");
            return resultado;
        }
        else return str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Few little tweaks:
a) don't close and open writer `bw` inside the loop - it is inefficient to close/open it on each iteration (time consuming).
b) you don't want to work on temporary String here: `String str = a;` working on original will be more efficient and correct.
c) similar here: `String nueva = rs.replace(line);` you don't need new String. Assign result to old `line`.

Regarding why some lines are missing - check if you programs returns with exception (or catch it, don't throw, so it is easier to see). I can't see the reason now.

Comment: Same to @rmuller I did, i just was trying if it work inside the loop (?) but it didn't, i will try your b and c and ill post what happenned, thanks.

Comment: I tried points b) and c) and nothing happened, and I try catched IOException and there's no IO exception. but thanks for the points

Comment: No problem. That was just little tweaks that would make you code better. But as I said I can't see any reason for your problem. cheers